# missing : after property id when minifying with yuicompressor

Tags: javascript

I have to call an external app on my website with:

```
  const { toggle  } = window.cdn.createAnimation('Ff8rx6E4'); 
  document.querySelector('#btn-mobile-openapp').onclick = toggle;
```

This works surprisingly ok. But when I am trying to minify the file, it runs a js validity check and I am getting:

```
missing : after property id
```

The regular onclick or eventlisteners won't work here. Any ideas how to correctly define toggle without running into an error?

Comment: Where is your element with id=btn-mobile-openapp?

Comment: How exactly are you minifying the file?

Comment: @deceze yuicompressor - the answer below has helped now and it minifies fine

Comment: Might be a better idea to use a tool that supports modern Javascript version, or tweak some setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to me like the minifier isn't aware of destructuring. Try switching the JavaScript to

```
  const animation = window.cdn.createAnimation('Ff8rx6E4'); 
  document.querySelector('#btn-mobile-openapp').onclick = animation.toggle;
```

Or there could be some invisible character in your `{ toggle  }`? I can see 2 spaces before the closing }.

Failing that, what are you using to minify?

Comment: No, spaces didn't change a thing. But your solution charmingly worked. Thanks!

Comment: I use yuicompressor under linux

Comment: Glad it helped! I didn't downvote, but I guess people may have thought 2 lines isn't enough, and have questions like. "What minifier is he using", "Where is other contextual code like the #btn-mobile-openapp HTML", "What have you done to attach cdn.createAnimation to the window object?", etc. All useful info to add to get the best answer.

Comment: I think people have different thresholds over what is a minimal amount on a question to warrant engaging. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

This JavaScript exception `missing : after property id` occurs if objects are declared using the object’s initialization syntax. It can happen when there is a mistake in the object initializer syntax somewhere. Might be in fact a missing curly bracket, but could also be a missing comma.

In your case, since it's only occuring in minification and by looking at your code, try to use it in a regular assignment instead of the object destructuring way which might be the cause for the error.

```
const animate = window.cdn.createAnimation('Ff8rx6E4'); 
document.querySelector('#btn-mobile-openapp').onclick = animate.toggle;
```